# UnitTest C++ in VS (expected and actual values are the same but it's showing the mistake)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

Why is it showing that the test failed, but the expected and actual values are the same? What is the problem?

[image: image (Assert failed)]

```
    #include "pch.h"
    #include "CppUnitTest.h"
    #include "../Lab 5_3/Lab 5_3.cpp"
    
    using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
    
    namespace UnitTest53
    {
        TEST_CLASS(UnitTest53)
        {
        public:
            
            TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
            {
                double t, g;
                g = 1;
                t = p(p(1 - 2 * g) + pow(p(1 - p(1) + (p(2 * g) * p(2 * g))), 2));
                Assert::AreEqual(t, 0.320469);
    
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: More than likely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) is your issue, and the display is just not printing out the full resolution of those variables so they look equal, but aren't

Comment: Something something floating point equality is a myth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Basically problems is that there is a rounding issue for floating point types. For details see [this linked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).
Results of calculation should not be compared by equal operator, but some tolerance must be applied.

Now `CppUnitTestFramework` takes this into account and gives you a chance to provide this tolerance. So fix your test like this:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "../Lab 5_3/Lab 5_3.cpp"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTest53
{
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest53)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            double t, g;
            g = 1;
            t = p(p(1 - 2 * g) + pow(p(1 - p(1) + (p(2 * g) * p(2 * g))), 2));
            Assert::AreEqual(t, 0.320469, 0.000001);

        }
    };
}
```

Reference: [CppUnitTestFramework API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019#general_are_equal)

> Verify that two doubles are equal
>
> ```cpp
> static void Assert::AreEqual(
>        double expected,
>        double actual,
>        double tolerance,
>        const wchar_t* message = NULL,
>        const __LineInfo* pLineInfo = NULL)
> ```

Since you used only 2 arguments for `AreEqual` your code used this template:

```cpp
template<typename T>
static void Assert::AreEqual(
    const T& expected,
    const T& actual,
    const wchar_t* message = NULL,
    const __LineInfo* pLineInfo = NULL)
```

which just uses equal operator.